# upgrade from xp to windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Should I upgrade from XP Professional to Vista Business and then upgrade to Windows 7 Professional? Or, try to do this "migration" thing from XP to Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use the migration tool John T mentioned. With upgrades you get some "cruft" left from the previous install slowing the system down. With 2 upgrades it's almost guaranteed that you end up with an extremely slow system.

Comment: Yeah, upgrade plus upgrade would equal a very messy install.  I'm not a big fan of upgrades in the first place but I think you would be better suited by going straight to 7.  Plus if you have to reload your system often like I do, my wife and 2 year old can be hard on a computer, then do you want to have to load 3 operating systems or 2?

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself some time and just use the **User State Migration Tool** from Microsoft. [This video on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd671583.aspx) explains the process in detail.